# Webpack-dev-server SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: express, webpack

I have a multipage react app running with webpack on http://localhost:3000.
When I run `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline` and go to `http://localhost:3000/movies`, my component does not render and console says

```
bundle.js:17 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:1:47124)
    at w (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:33:9889)
    at Generator._invoke (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:33:9677)
    at Generator.e.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:33:10068)
    at i (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:1:47400)
    at a (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:1:47495)
    at <anonymous>
```

When I run the app with `react-scripts start` (yarn), I **dont** get the error.
 Fyi the app uses `react-router` and on page load makes a json api call to a node express in the back. Express runs on port 5000

My webpack config is

```
const path = require('path');

const package = require('./package.json');

const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
    public: path.join(__dirname, './public')
};

var config = {
    entry: { 
        app: [ 'babel-polyfill', path.resolve(PATHS.src, 'index.js') ] 
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(PATHS.public),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(PATHS.public),
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            use: [
                { 
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                }
                ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [
                { 
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
                ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader",
                    options: { singleton: true }
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: { 
                        modules: true,
                        camelCase: 'dashes',
                        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]' 
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

I dont know if its just a json issue, the react app is not directly 'requiring' .json files, it is requesting a json response from node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react doing a `fetch` was actually getting an html response `JSON.parse('<...')`.

the middleware in webpack-dev-server was overriding the proxy in package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

I added this to the devServer config

```
proxy: {
   '/api/**': {
   target: 'http://localhost:5000',
   changeOrigin: true
}
```

it didnt work still, so I also removed the proxy line from package.json. That fixed it.